# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool

Tags: php, mysql

i have some problem on SQL that says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool" i've tried my best to solve it but it getting messed up. pls Help

```
$cekFore3 = $koneksi->query("SELECT fore3 from peramalan ORDER BY id_produk DESC LIMIT 1");
$cekFore5 = $koneksi->query("SELECT fore5 from peramalan ORDER BY id_produk DESC LIMIT 1");

while($data3 = $cekFore3->fetch_object()) {
    $d3[] = $data3;
}
foreach ($d3 as $val3) {
    $e3 = $val3->sma3;
} // LAST FORECAST VALUE 3

while ($data5 = $cekfore5->fetch_object()) {
    $d5[] = $data5;
}
foreach ($d5 as $val5) {
    $e5 = $val5->sma5;
} // LAST FORECAST 5
```

Comment: You have an error in one of the queries. Either the column names or table names are wrong.

Comment: Why are you using loops and arrays when the queries have `LIMIT 1`?